# How to delete all the cookies of the browser in php

Tags: javascript, php, session, cookies

consider i have three websites in a different server namely example1.com,example2.com,example3.com

i have tried to clear all the cookies when i click the particular logout page.But, it clear only the current page cookies.

i opened all these websites in the browser ..and now when i logout from the example1.com it should clear all the cookies of the browser whichever has been set previously...

Thanks in Advance.

My code::

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer you cant, you would need to do some funky redirects to all the domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

For obvious security reasons. You can't read (and delete) cookies that belongs to another domain. If you could, than all website would have access to all cookies in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Posting it as an answer due to less reputation.

basically cookies are save on browsers and relation between browser and web server regarding cookies is that data present  at eligible requests
so , expiration of cookie is correct method because it means data is no more, by the following two method you delete your cookie form browser

1) unset($_COOKIE['my_cookie']);
2) setcookie('my_cookie', '', 1); //  1 is time of past